# how does 'undefined' work in Haskell

Tags: haskell, undefined

I'm curious about the 'undefined' value in Haskell. Its interesting because you can put it just about anywhere, and Haskell will be happy. The following are all a-ok

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0 , undefined]  ::[Float]
[1, 2 ,3 undefined, 102312] :: [Int]
("CATS!", undefined)  :: (String, String)
....and many more
```

How does undefined work under the hood? What makes it possible to have data that is of every data type? Would it be possible for me to define a value like this that I can put everywhere, or is this some special case?

Comment: `let undef = undef` `let f x = x + undef` `let f x = head undef`, etc... and from the type of `undef` which is `t` we can see that it can be replaced by any type, hence it can be used anywhere anything of some type is expected.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's nothing really special about `undefined`. It is just an exceptional value -- you could represent it with an infinite loop, or a crash, or a segfault. One way to write it is as a crash:

```
undefined :: a
undefined | False = undefined
```

Or a loop:

```
undefined = undefined
```

It is an exceptional value that can be an element of any type.

Since Haskell is lazy you can still use such values in computations. E.g.

```
 > length [undefined, undefined]
 2
```

But otherwise, it is just a natural consequence of polymorphism and non-strictness.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Out of interest why would removing undefined from Haskell mess with turing completeness? I personally have never had to use it in a program. Is it more that something (crash, infinite loop, segfault) etc. has to exist for turing completeness and undefined > infinite loop as it crashes immediately with an error message?

Comment: @semicolon It's more simple than that. Since Haskell let's us directly represent Turing Complete computations (sorry, @pigworker!) it means that it's always going to have `undefined`. If `undefined` was not defined for us then we could always define it as `undefined :: a; undefined = let x = x in x`. This has the same *semantics* as `undefined` (though different observable behavior) from the perspective of Haskell-the-language.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson ah I see. So basically the only way to prevent it from existing would be to heavily restrict what the user can do, basically needing to prove the users code correct. Which is impossible to do for every arbitrary problem, and a turing complete language can solve any arbitrary problem.

Comment: @semicolon That's basically the idea. Another way to look at it is that types in Haskell are not strong enough to talk about Haskell's completeness and therefore the type system has a hole where it cannot "see" infinite loops.

Answer (score 32):

The interesting property you're examining is that `undefined` has the type `a` for any type `a` we choose, i.e. `undefined :: a` with no constraints. As others have noted, `undefined` might be thought of as an error or infinite loop. I'd like to argue that it's better thought of as "the vacuously true statement". It's an almost unavoidable hole in any type system closely related to the Halting Problem, but it's fun to think about it from the point of view of logic.

---

One way to think about programming with types is that it's a puzzle. Someone gives you a type and asks you to implement a function which is of that type. For instance

```
Question:    fn  ::  a -> a
Answer:      fn  =  \x -> x
```

is an easy one. We need to produce an `a` for any type `a`, but we're given one as an input so we can just return that.

With `undefined`, this game is always easy

```
Question:    fn  ::  Int -> m (f [a])
Answer:      fn  =  \i   -> undefined    -- backdoor!
```

so let's be rid of it. Making sense of `undefined` is easiest when you live in a world without it. Now our game gets harder. Sometimes it's possible

```
Question:    fn  :: (forall r. (a -> r) -> r) -> a
Answer:      fn  =  \f                        -> f id
```

But suddenly it's sometimes not possible as well!

```
Question:    fn  ::  a -> b
Answer:      fn  =   ???                  -- this is `unsafeCoerce`, btw.
                                          -- if `undefined` isn't fair game,
                                          -- then `unsafeCoerce` isn't either
```

Or is it?

```
-- The fixed-point combinator, the genesis of any recursive program

Question:    fix  ::  (a -> a) -> a
Answer:      fix  =   \f       -> let a = f a in a

                                          -- Why does this work?
                                          -- One should be thinking of Russell's 
                                          -- Paradox right about now. This plays
                                          -- the same role as a non-wellfounded set.
```

Which is legal because Haskell's `let` binding is lazy and (generally) *recursive*. Now we're golden.

```
Question:    fn   ::  a -> b
Answer:      fn   =  \a -> fix id         -- This seems unfair?
```

Even without having `undefined` built-in we can rebuild it in our game using any old infinite loop. The types check out. To truly prevent ourselves from having `undefined` in Haskell we'd need to solve the Halting Problem.

```
Question:    undefined  ::  a
Answer:      undefined  =   fix id
```

---

Now, as you've seen, `undefined` is useful for debugging since it can be a placeholder for any value. It's unfortunately terrible for operations since it either leads to an infinite loop or an immediate crash. It's also really bad for our game because it lets us cheat. Finally, I hope I've demonstrated that it's pretty hard to *not* have `undefined` so long as your language has (potentially infinite) loops.

There exist languages like Agda and Coq which trade away loops in order to truly eliminate `undefined`. They do this because this game I've invented can, in some cases, actually be very valuable. It can encode statements of logic and thus be used to form very, very rigorous mathematical proofs. Your types represent theorems and your programs are assurances that that theorem is substantiated. The existence of `undefined` would mean that all theorems are substantiatable and thus make the whole system untrustworthy.

But in Haskell, we're more interested in looping than proofing, so we'd rather have `fix` than  be certain there wasn't an `undefined`.

Comment: I think this is a very good answer, but it should have some breadcrumbs for anyone who's interested in developing it further, e.g. the Curry-Howard correspondence.

Comment: Not all infinite loops are useless: http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/07/data-and-codata.html . And if you really want Turing-completeness, you can't rule out all non-terminating programs.

Comment: Yes—both of these are worth mentioning as followups.

Comment: There's a problem with characterizing `undefined` as "the vacuously true statement," though, which is that it makes it sound like `undefined` corresponds to a tautological statement in logic, when nothing could be farther from the truth (ahem). In logical terms, allowing ourselves to have `undefined :: forall a. a` is fundamentally like saying that we have a proof for any statement `a`, no matter what `a` is—but logically speaking, this entails we can prove contradictions!

Comment: "vacuous" is the wrong word, true. Unit, (), is vacuously true.

Comment: @tel, weren't you right the first time?  "vacuous" seems exactly correct to me.  `undefined` is a member of the bottom type, and given an element of that set we can prove anything.  However, the bottom type is empty by definition, therefore any proofs relying upon it are vacuously true, i.e. they don't actually imply the truth of the consequence.  I don't see that `()` can be vacuously true, because `()` isn't empty.

Comment: @JohnL "Vacuously true" is usually used of statements like "every element of the empty set is greater than 5"; it's technically a true statement, but only because it doesn't say anything that could possibly be false, rather than because it actually tells us anything. `undefined`'s truthiness is quite a different kind of thing. Rather than being devoid of information content it claims to be a proof of everything! Rather than being true but boring, `undefined` is something we would rather think of as *false*, but it's technically true in the formal system.

Comment: @Ben that's my point.  The bottom type is the empty set.  `undefined :: forall t. t` claims to be instantiable at the bottom type, so it's claiming to be a member of the empty set.  Therefore every "proof" based on `undefined` is equivalent to "every element of the empty set is {true}" (or whatever the proof is).  Vacuously, technically true, but devoid of content.  undefined's purported proof of everything is contingent upon `undefined` existing at all!  Since it cannot, the consequent proofs are all vacuously true.

Comment: I think "vacuous" is sufficiently non-technical here that it's hard (for me) to argue for or against it. For that reason, I'd change it in my answer if a better choice existed. As it is, `undefined` is, in my mind, sufficiently meaningless in a logical setting as to not have any really good ways to describe it—the result of `ex_falso` after applying `bottom`? The best thing you can note about it is that it (a) arises naturally out of general recursion and (b) breaks my game. A good thing to do would be to compare `let x = f x in x` to Russell's paradox, perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

How does `undefined` work?  Well, the best answer, IMHO, is that **it doesn't work**.  But to understand that answer, we have to work through its consequences, which are not obvious to a newcomer.

Basically, if we have `undefined :: a`, what that means for the type system is that `undefined` can appear anywhere.  Why?  Because in Haskell, whenever you see an expression that has some type, you can *specialize* the type by consistently substituting all instances of any of its type variables for any other type.  Familiar examples would be things like this:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]

-- Substitute b := b -> x
map :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b -> c]

-- Substitute a := Int
map :: (Int -> b -> c) -> [Int] -> [b -> c]

-- etc.
```

In the case of `map`, how does this work?  Well, it comes down to the fact that `map`'s arguments provide everything that's necessary to produce an answer, no matter what substitutions and specializations we make for its type variables.  If you have a list and a function that consumes values of the same type as the list's elements, you can do what map does, period.

But in the case of `undefined :: a`, what this signature would mean is that no matter what type `a` may get specialized to, `undefined` is able to produce a value of that type.  How can it do it?  Well, actually, it can't, so if a program actually reaches a step where the value of `undefined` is needed, there is no way to continue.  The only thing the program can do at that point is to fail

The story behind this other case is similar but different:

```
loop :: a
loop = loop
```

Here, we can prove that `loop` has type `a` by this crazy-sounding argument: suppose that `loop` has type `a`.  It needs to produce a value of type `a`.  How can it do it?  Easy, it just calls `loop`.  Presto!

That sounds crazy, right?  Well, the thing is that it's really no different from what's going on in the second equation of this definition of `map`:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

In that second equation, `f x` has type `b`, and `(f x:)` has type `[b] -> [b]`; now to conclude our proof that `map` indeed has the type our signature claims, we need to produce a `[b]`.  So how are we doing it?  By assuming that `map` has the type we're trying to prove it has!

The way Haskell's type inference algorithm works is that it first guesses that the expression's type is `a`, and then it only changes its guess when it finds something that contradicts that assumption.  `undefined` typechecks to `a` because it's a flat-out lie.  `loop` typechecks to `a` because recursion is allowed, and all `loop` does is recurse.

---

**EDIT:** What the heck, I might as well spell out one example.  Here's an informal demonstration of how to infer the type of `map` from this definition:

```
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

It goes like this:

1. We start by provisionally assuming that `map :: a`.
2. But map takes two arguments, so `a` can't be the type.  We revise our assumption to this: `map :: a -> b -> c; f :: a`.
3. But as we can see in the first equation, the second argument is a list: `map :: a -> [b] -> c; f :: a`.
4. But as we can also see in the first equation, the result is also a list: `map :: a -> [b] -> [c]; f :: a`.
5. In the second equation, we're pattern matching the second argument against the constructor `(:) :: b -> [b] -> [b]`.  This means that in that equation, `x :: b` and `xs :: [b]`.
6. Consider the right hand side of the second equation.  Since the result of `map f (x:xs)` must be of type `[c]`, that means `f x : map f xs` must also be of type `[c]`.
7. Given the type of the constructor `(:) :: c -> [c] -> [c]`, that means that `f x :: c` and `map f xs :: [c]`.
8. In (7) we concluded that `map f xs :: [c]`.  We had assumed that in (6), and if we had concluded otherwise in (7) this would have been a type error.  We can also now dive into this expression and see what types this requires `f` and `xs` to have, but to make a longer story short, everything's going to check out.
9. Since `f x :: c` and `x :: b`, we must conclude that `f :: b -> c`.  So now we get `map :: (b -> c) -> [b] -> [c]`.
10. We're done.

The same process, but for `loop = loop`:

1. We provisionally assume that `loop :: a`.
2. `loop` takes no arguments, so its type is consistent with `a` so far.
3. The right hand side of `loop` is `loop`, which we've provisionally assigned type `a`, so that checks out.
4. There's nothing more to consider; we're done.  `loop` has type `a`.

Comment: "Expression X has type A" means that evaluating X will either produce a value of type A or diverge. If you want a type system where "expression X has type A" will mean "evaluating X converges and yields a value of type A", you will have to give up on Turing-completeness.

Answer (score 2):

Well, basically `undefined = undefined` — if you try evaluate it, you get an endless loop. But Haskell is a non-strict language, so `head [1.0, 2.0, undefined]` doesn't evaluate *all* elements of the list, so it prints `1.0` and terminates. But if you print `show [1.0, 2.0, undefined]`, you'll see `[1.0,2.0,*** Exception: Prelude.undefined`.

As of how it can be of all types... Well, if expression is of type `A`, it means that evaluating it either will yield value of type `A`, or the evaluation will diverge, yielding no value at all. Now, `undefined` always diverge, so it fits into definition for every imaginable type `A`.

Also, a good blog post on the related topics: http://james-iry.blogspot.ru/2009/08/getting-to-bottom-of-nothing-at-all.html

Comment: But it's not a loop See http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html#$vundefined and http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Err.html#undefined

Comment: @cheecheeo: it's not defined as a loop, but GHC permits them to have the same semantics.  `undefined` is `error` which throws an `ErrorCall` exception.  Defining `let loop = loop` creates a detectable bottom, for which the implementation is allowed to throw a `NonTermination` exception.  Since bottoms are more or less interchangeable semantically, it doesn't matter which is thrown (and knowing that it's explicitly `undefined` is more useful than the generic non-termination exception).

Answer (score 1):

If I try `undefined` in GHCi, I get an exception:

```
Prelude> undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

Therefore, I suppose that it's just implemented as throwing an exception:
http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Exception.html#g:2

Answer (score 1):

There are two separated things to note about undefined:

- You can put undefined almost everywhere and typechecker will be happy. It's because undefined have type (forall a. a).
- You can put undefined almost everywhere and it will have some well defined representation at run time.

For the second, [GHC commentary](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects) clearly says:

> The representation of ⊥ must be a pointer: it is an object that when evaluated throws an exception or enters an infinite loop.

For more details you might want to read the paper [Spinless Tagless G-Machine](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=67083).